# How/where do I change the getFieldParams for magento forms from required-entry to just required?

Tags: forms, validation, form-validation

I'm TRYING to convert a magento template to use Foundation 5, running into all kinds of issues with forms.

How/where do I change the getFieldParams for magento form validation from required-entry to say "required"?

Comment: Just to clarify. the class should be `required` in the html? Is this frontend? And could you also state in which forms?

Comment: yup - front end. Specifically the register form at the moment, but it will be all forms at some point.  I did find the markup in the modernizr validation.js script then copied it to a validation-custom.js and substituted that in my local.xml with the new markup for the error output.  HOWEVER in my opinion, this is a terrible place to put markup and it's absolutely wrong to modify distribution files.  [in a .js file]  - is there even a way to customize this other than modifying distribution files?

Comment: one more thing. What version of Magento are you using?

Comment: version 1.9.x CE